# XML File convert to C# object

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have to read this XML File in a C# Object. That i have these information in an Object. 
 Not all tags are important!
 
These would be the important information i need in the Object:
 - Alignment with the staStart Property
 - CoordGoem with Line Spiral and Curve inside and of thesse are only the properties important

### XML File

```
<Alignments name="">
    <Alignment name="AL-voor omvorming landxml" length="6550.000000000015" staStart="30000." desc="">
        <CoordGeom>
            <Line dir="0." length="100.">
                <Start>175.282796686952 -1708.474133524573</Start>
                <End>175.282796686952 -1608.474133524573</End>
            </Line>
            <Spiral length="100." radiusEnd="500." radiusStart="INF" rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="5.729577951308" totalY="3.330953138396" totalX="99.900046285614" tanLong="66.701620764677" tanShort="33.365112106501">
                <Start>175.282796686952 -1608.474133524573</Start>
                <PI>175.282796686952 -1541.772512759896</PI>
                <End>171.951843548555 -1508.574087238959</End>
            </Spiral>
            <Curve rot="cw" chord="99.833416646828" crvType="arc" delta="11.459155902616" dirEnd="342.811266146075" dirStart="354.270422048692" external="2.510459200228" length="100." midOrd="2.497917360987" radius="500." tangent="50.167336042725">
                <Start>171.951843548555 -1508.574087238959</Start>
                <Center>-325.550239090457 -1558.490795562373</Center>
                <End>152.118005472345 -1410.730692231703</End>
                <PI>166.94346698734 -1458.657378915545</PI>
            </Curve>
            <Spiral length="100." radiusEnd="INF" radiusStart="500." rot="cw" spiType="clothoid" theta="5.729577951308" totalY="3.330953138396" totalX="99.900046285614" tanLong="66.701620764677" tanShort="33.365112106501">
                <Start>152.118005472345 -1410.730692231703</Start>
                <PI>142.257940647353 -1378.855783172596</PI>
                <End>116.283106059873 -1317.419522049479</End>
            </Spiral>
```

### Object

```
public class LandXMLAlignments
{
    public long staStart { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("CoordGeom")]
    public List<LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeom> CoordGeoms { get; set; }
}

public class LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeom
{
    public List<LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeomLine> CoordGeomLines { get; set; }
    public List<LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeomSpiral> CoordGeomSpiral { get; set; }
    public List<LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeomLine> CoordGeomCurve { get; set; }
}
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType("Line", IncludeInSchema = true)]
public class LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeomLine
{
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int position { get; set; }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType("Spiral", IncludeInSchema = true)]
public class LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeomSpiral
{
    public int position { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public string radiusStart { get; set; }
    public string radiusEnd { get; set; }
    public string rot { get; set; }
    public string spiType { get; set; }
}
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType("Curve", IncludeInSchema = true)]
public class LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeomCurve
{
    public int position { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int radiusStart { get; set; }
    public string rot { get; set; }
}
```

I would have drawn this object from it but i don't now how i actually read the xml file in this Object.

Comment: "_I_ _do_ _not_ _know_ _how_ _to_ _continue_" Pease describe better your problem. BTW, I wonder why your properties are private, you could not access them.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio you could just create a class with Edit -> Paste special... and the use your favorite deserializer . am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your classes are ok you could just create a helper class to perfom transformations from XML to a POCO object like this:

```
public static class XmlHelper
{
    public static T ParseXmlFile<T>(string filePath)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            T configuration = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            return configuration;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var  alignments = XmlHelper.ParseXmlFile<LandXMLAlignments>(YourXMLPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication51
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Alignments));
            Alignments alignments = (Alignments)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    public class Alignments
    {
        [XmlElement("Alignment")]
        public Alignment alignment { get; set; }
    }
    public class Alignment
    {
        public long staStart { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("CoordGeom")]
        public List<LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeom> CoordGeoms { get; set; }
    }

    public class LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeom
    {
        [XmlElement("Line")]
        public List<LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeomLine> CoordGeomLines { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Spiral")]
        public List<LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeomSpiral> CoordGeomSpiral { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Curve")]
        public List<LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeomLine> CoordGeomCurve { get; set; }
    }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType("Line", IncludeInSchema = true)]
    public class LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeomLine
    {
        public int length { get; set; }
        public int position { get; set; }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType("Spiral", IncludeInSchema = true)]
    public class LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeomSpiral
    {
        public int position { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
        public string radiusStart { get; set; }
        public string radiusEnd { get; set; }
        public string rot { get; set; }
        public string spiType { get; set; }
    }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType("Curve", IncludeInSchema = true)]
    public class LandXMLAlignmentsCoordGeomCurve
    {
        public int position { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
        public int radiusStart { get; set; }
        public string rot { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual studio, then do the following:

1. Copy XML
2. Select Edit Menu,
3. Paste Special, Paste XML as Classes.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/generating-data-type-classes-from-xml#creating-the-data-types)